# How to import a file(that is at project's root level) in a package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, path

I am writing a NPM package where I want to import a config file which will be at the home directory of the project.

The most known example would be Babel, Babel uses `babel.config.js` located at the home directory in the project to read its configuration.

Example Structure -

```
src
node_modules
  package1
   index.js // Here we need to read config.js file
package.json
config.js
```